# how to make colab use GPU for spacy training NER model

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, transformer-model

I have **40,000** records and I the training process is very *slow*, this is the line I use in colab for training

```
! python -m spacy train config.cfg --output /content/ --paths.train /content/training_data.spacy --paths.dev /content/training_data.spacy
```

when I run this cell, this show up

> ℹ Saving to output directory: /content
>
> ℹ Using CPU
>
> ℹ To switch to GPU 0, use the option: --gpu-id 0

I want to use the `GPU` but when I use the `--gpu-id 0` in end of cell command, I got `ERROR`

and I changed runtime of colab to GPU

Answer (score 4):

The key steps to make it happen are:

1. enable the GPU (edit -> notebook settings -> hardware acceleration)
2. install spacy with CUDA support (`pip install spacy[cuda100]`)
3. Validate if it is all set by running the following code (it must return `True`):

```
import spacy

gpu = spacy.prefer_gpu()
print(gpu)
```

If it is true, then your env is ready to run spacy with GPU support.

Comment: I use that but I got the ERROR `ValueError: Out shape is mismatched`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with spacy and GPU -- my best guess is that you may have wrong vector dimensions inside your spacy code.

Comment: just to reinforce -- that's the output you must see to validate that spacy is accessing the GPU device on colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14UchBrNwYDyEg8qZvGppPwaW5flAmu2C?usp=sharing

Comment: Using `prefer_gpu` to check that the GPU is working is correct, but you shouldn't install CUDA yourself on Colab - they have special versions of CUDA libraries pre-installed you should use because they have custom hardware.